# Firebird Embeded & .NET: fbembed.dll in different folder

Tags: .net, firebird

I want to specify the folder where to load the fbembed.dll from. In App.config I have:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="database" connectionString="Dialect=3;Database=Database\MYDATASTORAGE.FDB;ServerType=1;clientlibrary=Database\fbembed.dll"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But I still get the error even if the file is there:

```
The DLL library database\fbembed.dll cannot be loaded: Mentioned modul was not found.(Error based on the value of HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Is it needed to be .dll libraries in the root?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you will have better support in firebird .Net driver support list http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to add ".\" to the start of "Database\MYDATASTORAGE.FDB"?